# Prevent ajaxToolkit's ModalPopupExtender from closing in javascript

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have a ModalPopUpExtender from Ajax Toolkit, inside UpdatePanel, which i'm using to open asp Panel "PanelNewScrap".

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalNewScrapPopup" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" PopupControlID="PanelNewScrap" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" TargetControlID="HiddenNewScrapButton" CancelControlID="CloseNewScrapPopup" BehaviorID="MDPNewScrapPopup">
                        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

I have a textbox with ID="NumericBoxQuantityMin" inside asp panel 'PanelNewScrap'. I have attached a javascript function on 'onBlur' event of Textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="NumericBoxQuantityMin" runat="server" onblur="return ConfirmEdit();" AutoPostBack="true"                                                  onkeyup="extractNumber(this,0,true);" onkeypress="return blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, true);" />

//Javascript function ConfirmEdit:
function ConfirmEdit(){
return confirm('Are you sure?');
}
```

Whenever user click on 'OK' or 'Cancel', modalPopup closes!
I have tried writting $find("MDPNewScrapPopup").show(); but it close everytime.

I don't want modalpupup to close irrespective of outcome of ConfirmEdit() function.

Please help.

SOLUTION:
Removed AutoPostBack="true" and its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys!

removed AutoPostBack="true" and its working fine...